# How create MYSQL trigger to set duplicate value 'status' to 0 after insert?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here is my structure
I have a status column in my table and its default value is 1

I am trying to check if there is a duplicate value for the barcode column and if exists set the old record status to 0.

So far I tried this, please help me to correct this

```
CREATE TRIGGER dr_scan_dup
AFTER INSERT ON dr_scan
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dr_scan WHERE barcode = NEW.barcode)) THEN
   UPDATE dr_scan SET status ='0';
  END IF;
END
```

[image]

Here is my table and if someone inserts 300 into the barcode it should change the previous status value to 0

Comment: Can you provide more about your table `dr_scan` structure

Comment: Hi @AnujKarki I just updated.please refer it

Comment: Do you want to update a row other than inserted one in the trigger? This is absolutely impossible.

Comment: no no, i want to use the trigger to check if there is a duplicate value already in the table and if yes set duplicate (old)value status to 0

Comment: "Set another value in duplicated record" is "update another row". And, as I have said, this is impossible. Possible solution - the trigger inserts `id` for the row to be updated into service table. Event procedure which is executed each 1 second updates the row by `id` and removes this `id` from the service table.

Comment: @PasinduHettiarachchi, I am assuming column `id` is unique. Then you could try something like `UPDATE dr_scan SET status ='0' WHERE barcode = NEW.barcode AND id <>NEW.id`